# Show error message when button is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have a set of  tags which for showing time slots. when i submit the form without selecting button it read the time as null and store it as null.now i need to show an error message when time is not selected before submission.

```html
<div class="slot-list">
    <p class="slot_text">
      <i>* Time slots are in IST</i>
    </p>
<div class="time_scroll">    
  <div class="slot is-available">
      <button class="time-button" id="update" type="button" value="09">
          <span class="time-button-title">09.00am</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="slot is-available">
      <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="10">
          <span class="time-button-title">10.00am</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="slot is-available">
      <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="11">
          <span class="time-button-title">11.00am</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="slot is-available">
      <button class="time-button" id="update" type="button" value="12">
          <span class="time-button-title">12.00pm</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="slot is-available">
      <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="13">
          <span class="time-button-title">01.00pm</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="slot is-available">
      <button class="time-button" id="update" type="button" value="14">
          <span class="time-button-title">02.00pm</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="slot is-available">
      <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="15">
          <span class="time-button-title">03.00pm</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="slot is-available">
      <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="16">
          <span class="time-button-title">04.00pm</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="slot is-available">
      <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="17">
          <span class="time-button-title">05.00pm</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="slot is-available">
      <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="18">
          <span class="time-button-title">06.00pm</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here i am adding my html code.how should i alert when button is not selected? when i submit the form without selecting button it read the time as null and store it as null.now i need to show an error message when time is not selected before submission.

Comment: How is a button supposed to get selected? It can only be clicked right?

Comment: I assume what you mean is that you want to prevent the form from being submitted and alert the user they need to select a button when they click submit and haven't selected anything. If that is the case simply add an if statement to check if the value is null. If you post your js code I'd be happy to elaborate.

Comment: i mean when i am not click on any time it should show an error message "choose any time"

Comment: Side note: I see you have multiple elements with the same `id="update"`. if you want multiple elements to have the same identifier, use class. Id is meant for only one specific element (it's unique)

Comment: @sindhu do you want to show this error by default? Or once the user clicks submit? As in, you can show this error at the start and until the user clicks on a time, or you can show it once they click submit.

Comment: hai everone, one thing sholud need to add

Comment: now it shows alert but the form is submited.how solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this. I have added js codes here to validate.

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $('#timeVal').val($( this ).val())
});
function checkFn(){
  var timeVal = $('#timeVal').val();
  if(timeVal != ""){
    alert(timeVal);
  } else {
    alert("please select time");
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="some" onsubmit="return checkFn()">
  <div class="slot-list">
    <p class="slot_text">
      <i>* Time slots are in IST</i>
    </p>
    <div class="time_scroll">    
      <div class="slot is-available">
        <button class="time-button" id="update" type="button" value="09">
          <span class="time-button-title">09.00am</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="slot is-available">
        <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="10">
          <span class="time-button-title">10.00am</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="slot is-available">
        <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="11">
          <span class="time-button-title">11.00am</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="slot is-available">
        <button class="time-button" id="update" type="button" value="12">
          <span class="time-button-title">12.00pm</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="slot is-available">
        <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="13">
          <span class="time-button-title">01.00pm</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="slot is-available">
        <button class="time-button" id="update" type="button" value="14">
          <span class="time-button-title">02.00pm</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="slot is-available">
        <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="15">
          <span class="time-button-title">03.00pm</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="slot is-available">
        <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="16">
          <span class="time-button-title">04.00pm</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="slot is-available">
        <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="17">
          <span class="time-button-title">05.00pm</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="slot is-available">
        <button class="time-button"id="update" type="button" value="18">
          <span class="time-button-title">06.00pm</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="time" id="timeVal" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is still not valid because, `id` of HTML element should be [unique](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

Comment: yes it should be unique, but I followed with his code. he needs to update his button id's

Comment: just use `return false;` in the function inside the error block

Comment: its not working, i add e.preventDefault() it is submitting the form